# Automate: Enable WiFi Calling in GPS Coordinates

Tags: automation, automate

My goal is to configure my Android LG G5, running the stock ROM, to enable Wi-Fi calling when I'm at home.

I downloaded the Automate app from the Google Play Store. Next, I created a new workflow, and searched for a "block" (workflow step) to enable/disable WiFi calling. I searched under the **Connectivity**, **Telephony**, and **Settings** sections, and couldn't find this block type. However, there are all sorts of other settings for setting the cellular network type, enabling / disabling WiFi in general.

Is this a gap in the Automate app?

Comment: I don't use Automate but I think that *WiFi calling* is a network enabled function and is unlikely that you you would be be able to automate unless your device is rooted and probably use a Xposed module or app

Comment: You mean specific to my cell phone errors? I figured that might be the case.

Comment: No, I mean in general

Comment: Apps are not allowed to access such features. Even on a rooted device it may be difficult since Wi-Fi calling in managed by third-party (carrier) apps.